# Selenium won't run on my raspberry pi 3 Model B+

Tags: python, python-3, chromium, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Today I recieved my Raspberry pi 3 Model B+. I downloaded NOOBS and installed it on my raspberry pi. However, I cannot run a selenium browser on it. I have tried to install `iceweasel` but it says that package is not available. I tried and installed `FireFox-esr` but the python script crashes. I tried to use Chromium, but that also doesn't work. All the questions/answers to this problem I looked up, don't work in 2019.

So my question is. What version of selenium do I need to install, and what browser do I need? Can someone tell me the commands to use, as well as show me a quick test script (just to open the url `https://www.youtube.com` on selenium). I don't care what browser it is, I just want to get selenium to work (prefer chrome, but I don't mind).

---

My test script

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
#driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")

while(1):
    pass
```

Comment: NOOBS is not an operating system. What operating system do you use from it? Is it Raspbian? What version?

Answer (score 3):

I've got Selenium and Chromium/chromedriver working on my RaspPi 3 Model B Rev 1.2 running Buster.  Here's how I installed everything and below is code that works for me.

I started with update and dist-upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Install Selenium (if you haven't already):

`sudo pip install selenium`

Install chromedriver (these steps could prob be shortened, but they worked for me):

I got a .deb file from
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/chromium-chromedriver
I chose this one:
"chromium-chromedriver 65.0.3325.181-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 in armhf (Updates)"
which has the URL
http://launchpadlibrarian.net/361669488/chromium-chromedriver_65.0.3325.181-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_armhf.deb
(but note there is another version labeled “Release” that could be tried)
(this is an older version of chromedriver, but it gets updated in subsequent steps below)

So I ran

`wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/361669488/chromium-chromedriver_65.0.3325.181-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_armhf.deb`

then (following https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159094/how-to-install-a-deb-file-by-dpkg-i-or-by-apt):

`sudo dpkg -i chromium-chromedriver_65.0.3325.181-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_armhf.deb`

and

`sudo apt-get install -f`

Then,
`sudo reboot`
and
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

The dist-upgrade results showed that chromedriver was updated to version 74 (same as my Chromium)

I also installed a couple of other required packages:

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb
sudo pip install PyVirtualDisplay
sudo pip install xvfbwrapper
```

I then rebooted.

The following Python 2.7 code works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

print 'Starting ...'
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1600, 1200))
display.start()
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
print 'webdriver loaded'

# Navigate to target website
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com')

driver.save_screenshot('SeleniumChromiumTest.png')
print 'target page loaded adnd screenshot taken'
print 'Done'
```

Hope this helps, good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest switching to ChromeDriver and using a package from the Raspbian repo as described [here](https://ivanderevianko.com/2020/01/selenium-chromedriver-for-raspberrypi)

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver
```

Comment: I think that this is the simplest and faster method to use selenium. No need to specify the path when using it